# Pubnub javascript is not receiving callbacks or message for some reason

Tags: javascript, pubnub, subscribe

Just want to understand why my pubnub javascript code does not receive a message from a channel. I can subscribe and publish, but if another browser sends a new publish message, the other browser can not receive the message. heres my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
    subscribe_key: 'subscribe-key-here',
    publish_key: 'publish-key-here'
  });

  pubnub.subscribe({
    channel    : "my-channel",
    message    : function(m){ console.log(m) },
    callback   : function (message) { console.log("callback: ", message)},
    connect    : function() {

      console.log("Connected")
      pubnub.publish({
        channel: 'my_channel',
        message: { "color" : "blue" },
        callback : function(details) {
            console.log(details)
        }
      });
     },
     disconnect : function() { console.log("Disconnected") },
     reconnect  : function() { console.log("Reconnected") },
     error      : function() { console.log("Network Error") },
     restore    : true
  })
});
```

by the way this code is running/testing on my nodejs localhost server and in chrome and firefox browser.

Answer (score 3):

Code Bug - You have a typo in your channel name:

- `subscribe` uses `my_channel`
- `publish` uses `my-channel`

Also, you are using two parameters that mean the same thing in the [subscribe](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk#subscribe): `message` is an alias for `callback`

And for your [publish](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk#publish), `success` is an alias (in [JavaScript/Node v3.7.20+](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk)) for `callback` and it recommended (just because it makes more sense).

I have removed the `callback` parameter from your `subscribe` and replace `callback` with `success` in your code below.

Corrected code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
    subscribe_key: 'subscribe-key-here',
    publish_key: 'publish-key-here'
  });

  pubnub.subscribe({
    channel    : "my_channel",
    message    : function (message) { console.log("callback: ", message)},
    connect    : function() {

      console.log("Connected")
      pubnub.publish({
        channel: 'my_channel',
        message: { "color" : "blue" },
        success : function(details) {
            console.log(details)
        }
      });
     },
     disconnect : function() { console.log("Disconnected") },
     reconnect  : function() { console.log("Reconnected") },
     error      : function() { console.log("Network Error") },
     restore    : true
  })
});
```